# Retrieving the "Link_ID" within an API

Tags: json, api

I am using the Reddit API called Pushshift (https://github.com/pushshift/api)

I am trying to get the  "LINK_ID" for Reddit post based on the title of the search.

For example, I want to find out all Reddit posts that contain the word "Trump" in the title - and I want to get the LINK_ID for each one of these posts. When I search : https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?title=trump

I get the following results:

```
 "data": [
        {
            "all_awardings": [],
            "allow_live_comments": false,
            "author": "rajacreator",
            "author_flair_css_class": null,
            "author_flair_richtext": [],
            "author_flair_text": null,
            "author_flair_type": "text",
            "author_fullname": "t2_ouuxidx4",
            "author_is_blocked": false,
            "author_patreon_flair": false,
            "author_premium": false,
            "awarders": [],
            "can_mod_post": false,
            "contest_mode": false,
            "created_utc": 1663481539,
            "domain": "rajacreator.com",
            "full_link": "https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/xh8ui0/servants_of_the_damned_overview_trump_and_the/",
            "gildings": {},
            "id": "xh8ui0",
            "is_created_from_ads_ui": false,
            "is_crosspostable": false,
            "is_meta": false,
            "is_original_content": false,
            "is_reddit_media_domain": false,
            "is_robot_indexable": false,
            "is_self": false,
            "is_video": false,
            "link_flair_background_color": "",
            "link_flair_richtext": [],
            "link_flair_text_color": "dark",
            "link_flair_type": "text",
            "locked": false,
            "media_only": false,
            "no_follow": true,
            "num_comments": 0,
            "num_crossposts": 0,
            "over_18": false,
            "parent_whitelist_status": "all_ads",
            "permalink": "/r/news/comments/xh8ui0/servants_of_the_damned_overview_trump_and_the/",
            "pinned": false,
            "pwls": 6,
            "removed_by_category": "automod_filtered",
            "retrieved_on": 1663481550,
            "score": 1,
            "selftext": "",
            "send_replies": false,
            "spoiler": false,
            "stickied": false,
            "subreddit": "news",
            "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh3l",
            "subreddit_subscribers": 25211187,
            "subreddit_type": "public",
            "thumbnail": "default",
            "title": "Servants of the Damned overview: Trump and the giant law firm he actually paid",
            "total_awards_received": 0,
            "treatment_tags": [],
            "upvote_ratio": 1.0,
            "url": "https://rajacreator.com/servants-of-the-damned-review-trump-and-the-giant-law-firm-he-actually-paid/?utm_source=SocialAutoPoster",
            "url_overridden_by_dest": "https://rajacreator.com/servants-of-the-damned-review-trump-and-the-giant-law-firm-he-actually-paid/?utm_source=SocialAutoPoster",
            "whitelist_status": "all_ads",
            "wls": 6
        },
```

There seems to be nothing here about "LINK_ID".

- Can someone please show me how to get the LINK_ID?

Thank you!

Note: In the future - once I find the LINK_ID for a specific Reddit link, I would then like to extract all the comments posted for that Reddit link (e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/pushshift/comments/bcwqxb/get_all_comments_from_submission/)

Comment: Is it `id`? Also look at `full_link` and `permalink`—same value appears in each.

Comment: I am looking into this! Thanks!